# Link Button issue in Symbian Device

Tags: asp.net, mobile, symbian

In my device, S60 5th edition

OS: Symbian S60 5th Edition Browser: 7.1

Useragent: Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.4; Series60/5.0 NokiaN97-1/12.0.024; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1; en-us) AppleWebKit/525 (KHTML, like Gecko) BrowserNG/7.1.12344

There is no issue with cookies, cookies are working normally. But Link Button control do not works. Actually, as I think, ASP.NET server does not send javascript code to perform a post back. That's why It says '_doPostBack()' not found.

It got fixed if I change target framework version from 4.0 to 3.5.

What is the easiest solution for this problem..??

Answer (score 0):

The reason some that some controls do not work on Symbian browser is that .Net injects a javascript function called __dopostback() into the page.
The controls call this function to cause a postback.
Symbian has a problem with the double underscore and cannot find the function.
Although I do not know how to fix it, I do have a workaround;
My default.aspx page has a javascript function called __Redirect() which redirects to the normal page that uses link buttons etc. If a device that does not recognize the double underscore, they are not redirected and stay on this "basic" page. on this page, I use hyperlinks etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check if the same link button is not working on all sites? I think its a site specific issue considering the fact that .NET version change makes the button work. As for the "easiest" solution, its certainly not on the device.

Comment: but how can i know which site is using which .net version..??

Comment: It is definitely a Symbian problem. I have exactly the same issue. Link buttons work perfectly on every other browser I have tested.